# How / Should I Encrypt Variable Size Data with RSA (RSACryptoServiceProvider)

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

In my research I have found mixed messages on this subject so I'm looking for expertise to explain the best approach to encrypting variable amounts of data.

**Requirements:**

[Edit: Adding additional requirement #3 in response to comment]

1. I would like to use RSA for the public/private key encryption scheme
   so I can distribute the public key to an application that should
   encrypt data but should not know how to decrypt it
2. I need to support data lengths from 16 characters (credit card
   number) to kilobytes (serialized objects) and beyond.  Most of the
       data I encrypt will be small (credit cards, addresses, etc).
3. This is for encrypting data at rest.

**Options I'm Aware Of:**

1. **RSA-ONLY:** Use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt all data using public key. 
   Iterate through the data in blocks that are less than the key size
   minus padding.
2. **HYBRID:** Use `AesCryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt the data, calling
   `.GenerateKey()` and `.GenerateIV()` to generate a random key and IV.
   Then use RSACryptoServiceProvider to encrypt the above key and IV
   and prepend or append that to the data.

It seems to my the Hybrid approach gives me the best of both worlds.  Strong block cipher (AES) and distributed public key (RSA).

What are the pros and cons of these approaches?  What is the standard?  Surprisingly I have not found much opinion or information on the subject and would appreciate any references you might have.

**Bonus:**
I am rolling my own for various reasons including corporate licensing restrictions but I'm curious if there is a good standard opensource approach for C#.

Comment: Although TLS does a lot more as well, it pretty much does your 'HYBRID' approach.  If it is just for transport, why not just use SSL?

Comment: Thanks @dtryon this is for encrypting data at rest.  I edited my question based on your comment.

Comment: This sounds like it might be better for http://security.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @ITNinja Perhaps you're right but I'm definitely asking in the context of programming per se.  My question is security related but is definitely tagged and intended to be answered from a C# and/or programming perspective.  You could be right but I'll see if I can get an answer first.  If you're right, I'm not sure the best way to move the question there.

Comment: I've ported the [keyczar](http://keyczar.org) library to C#, it has a built in API for the [hybrid method](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Session-Encryption) It also features a simple key-rotation and authenticated encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in most cases RSA is used to encrypt a symetric key (you don't really need to encrypt the IV, but hey...)

if you use RSA for encryption of data (instead of a key) you might run into the ECB (Electronic Code Book mode) problem that is known in the context of symetric block cyphers: for a given key, a clear-text is always mapped to the same cypher-text ... that alone doesn't help in breaking the encryption, but it can leak information since an attacker can identify which data packages contain the same clear-texts

i'd choose the hybrid approach, because it's suitable for arbitrary sized data, and won't be prone to this information leak unless you choose ECB for the mode of operation (CBC - Cypher Block Chaining mode - should do)